# Volume of a box inside an ellipsoid: is it correct?

Tags: calculus, optimization

I gotta find the maximum volume of a box which edges are parallels to the coordinate axes and that is inside of the ellipsoid
$$\frac{x^{2}}{4}+\frac{y^{2}}{81}+\frac{z^{2}}{196}=1$$

Since the volume is
$$V=xyz$$
I found that $\lambda=42\sqrt{3}$ using Lagrange's method. So
$$x=\frac{2\sqrt{3}}{3},\quad y=3\sqrt{3},\quad z=\frac{14\sqrt{3}}{3}$$
and then
$$V=28\sqrt{3}$$
I want to know if what I've done is right.

Comment: do you only consider the 1st octant?

Comment: The exercise doesn't say anything about it.

Comment: The point is - why is the volume of the box $xyz$ and not $8xyz$?

Comment: There are 8 octants : )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transform the ellipsoid into the unit sphere – the scale factors are $2,9,14$ in the $xyz$ directions respectively. The cube inscribed in the unit sphere has edge length $\frac2{\sqrt3}$ and volume $\frac8{3\sqrt3}$. Multiplying this by $2,9,14$ gives the volume of the largest axis-aligned box in the ellipsoid as $224\sqrt3$ – eight times your answer, since you only calculated one octant.